# Integration Between Axes

Tags: integration, geometry, definite-integrals

The diagram shows the graph of $y=x^2$, where $a\in[1,∞]$. The area of the pink region is equal to the area of the blue region. Give two equations for $a$ in terms of $b$, and hence give $a$ in exact form and determine the size of the blue area. 
[image: Diagram of Problem]

So my first instinct was to take the integral of both to find the areas and say that $ab-1$ the area of the entire rectangle there minus the $1$ by $1$, is equal to $(\frac{a^3}{3}-\frac{1}{3})+(\frac{2}{3}b^\frac{3}{2}-\frac{2}{3})$
Of course this didn't really get me anywhere because it turned out to just be an identity. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

**Hints**

(1) Where have you used the fact that the blue and pink areas are equal?

(2) You also know that $b=a^2$ since $(a,b)$ lies on the graph.

Answer (score 1):

You should notice the following two facts:

The area of the regions are the same

> $\int\limits_1^a x^2~dx = \int\limits_1^b \sqrt{y}~dy$

The vertical line for $x=a$ intersects the curve at the same point as the horizontal line for $y=b$

> $b = a^2$

Now, perform some calculus and some algebra to find the exact values of each.

Comment: So would I get for a in my second equation $a=\sqrt[3]{2b^\frac{3}{2}+1}$

Answer (score 0):

Can someone try to solve it? I keep getting an answer a = 1, which is incorrect according to the mark scheme (and well, it also doesn't fit the domain).